Blazor Server, Authorization Attribute with AuthenticationStateProvider not working
Trying to implement Authentication and Authorization using AuthenticationStateProvider. After a lot of playing around, have most of it working. I am running into a couple of issues:

If I refresh the page the authorization is completely lost and I need to re-login.

The attribute mechanism does not seem to work, for example after logging in and going to the page with this attribute it sends me back to the login page:
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]


Not sure if the Attribute is available when using AuthenticationStateProvider, I have not seen any examples of them being used together. One other item is that I need to use interactive mode for some pages due to employing Blazorise.
The code is as follows:
Program.cs
using Blazored.Toast;
using Blazorise;
using Blazorise.Bootstrap5;
using Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

// This is a Blazor Server Application (NOT a Webassembly App)
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add service defaults & Aspire components.
builder.AddServiceDefaults();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
    AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
        options.LoginPath = "/";
        options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/accessdenied";
    });
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
{
    ops.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    ops.SlidingExpiration = true;
}); builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddOutputCache();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GlobalUserInfo>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
builder.Services
    .AddBlazorise(options =>
    {
        options.Immediate = true;
    })
    .AddBootstrap5Providers()
    .AddFontAwesomeIcons();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
{
    ops.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    ops.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.UseOutputCache();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
app.MapDefaultEndpoints();
app.Run();

Login.razor
@code {

    async void Authenticate()
    {
        var result = await LoginApi.Login(login);

        ((CustomAuthStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider)
                    .AuthenticateUser(user.UserName, user.Role);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/home"); 
    }
}

MyAttribute.razor
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]


UPDATE

So after many trails, I have something partially working. It enforces the Authorise attribute, also refresh but allows only one user to be logged in at a time in the browser. Have not verified if it will allow more than one login outside of the browser - it may not.
Basically I had to intercept the authorization and check it against the logged in user.
CustomAuthStateProvider.cs
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

namespace MyApp.Web.Utilities
{
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
  
        private ClaimsIdentity _identity = new();
        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(_identity);
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }

        public void AuthenticateUser(string userIdentifier, string role)
        {
            _identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            [new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userIdentifier), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role),], "Custom Authentication");
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(_identity);

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(
                Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
        }

        public async Task LogUserOut()
        {
            _identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(_identity);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
        }
    }
}

CustomAuthorizationHandler.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

namespace MyApp.Web.Utilities
{
    public class CustomAuthorizationHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
    {
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authStateProvider;

        public CustomAuthorizationHandler(AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider)
        {
            _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
        }
        public Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
        {
            var result = _authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            context.User = result.Result.User;
            return next(context);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
using Blazored.Toast;
using Blazorise;
using Blazorise.Bootstrap5;
using Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome;
using MyApp.Web.APIClients;
using MyApp.Web.Components;
using MyApp.Web.Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

// This is a Blazor Server Application (NOT a Webassembly App)
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add service defaults & Aspire components.
builder.AddServiceDefaults();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, 

CustomAuthStateProvider>(); // To handle Authentication
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, CustomAuthorizationHandler>(); 
builder.Services.AddOutputCache();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
builder.Services
    .AddBlazorise(options =>
    {
        options.Immediate = true;
    })
        .AddBootstrap5Providers()
        .AddFontAwesomeIcons();
    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ops =>
    {
        ops.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        ops.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAntiforgery();
    app.UseOutputCache();
    app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
    app.MapDefaultEndpoints();
    app.Run();

So it basically stored the authenticated User and then compares it to the request when putting the path directly into the browser. I would be happy with the solution if it supported multiple users, but it does not since it is a Singleton. Scoped did not work.

Could you share the code of CustomAuthStateProvider? Even you refresh, the provider should be triggered again, so there should be some issue how you implement the provider.

@QuingFu Updated the post to where I am now. thx

Singleton service share across all requests and user sessions. It doesn't have one instance for each user.
The authenticationProvider shouldn't "save" user's identity. You will need to save the identity to somewhere else which different for each user and doesn't lost when refresh (such as cookie). Then use GetAuthenticationStateAsync to extra user principal from that cookie every time. But before that you need to know that different rendermode you will access cookie by different way How can I programmatically determine the Blazor render mode.
Firstly, Add following script to App.razor for create and read cookie:
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script>
        function WriteCookie(name, value, days) {
            var expires;
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }
            else {
                expires = "";
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        function ReadCookie(name) {
            console.log("test");
            const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
            const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
            if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
        }
    </script>

Then you could try following by saving and reading serilized claims in a cookie.
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IJSRuntime js;

        public CustomAuthStateProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IJSRuntime js)
        {
            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            this.js = js;
        }
        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            string token = "";
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
            {
                if (!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
                {

                    token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["token"];
                }
                else
                {
 
                    token = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("ReadCookie", "token");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                token = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("ReadCookie", "token");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            }

            var claims=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Claim>>(token);
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom Authentication");
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(identity)));
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateUser(string userIdentifier, string role)
        {

            List<Claim> claims =new();
            if (userIdentifier != "")
            {
                claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userIdentifier),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)
                };
            }
           
            var token=JsonSerializer.Serialize(claims);

            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
            {
                if (!_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
                {

                    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", token);
                }
                else
                {
                    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("WriteCookie", "token", token, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await js.InvokeVoidAsync("WriteCookie", "token", token, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));

            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom Authentication");
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity))));
        }

        public async Task LogUserOut()
        {
            await AuthenticateUser("", "");
           
        }
    }

This cookie will has nothing to do with the cookieAuthenticationScheme. It only save and provide information for AuthstateProvider. So no need for AddAuthentication().AddCookie() services. Just add following to program.cs
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped< IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, CustomAuthorizationHandler > ();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

And don't forget change the Route.razor to AuthorizeRouteView
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />

Another thing to mention is that this way considered wasm mode can only access browser storage. If you stick with the InteractiveServer, using server session storage is also a good choice.

Thanks for the information. Need to wrap up a few other things and will give this a try. I definitely want to stay with the server side approach.
